# Newly added methods throw exception in session bean

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, javabeans

This is the session bean class which i made.
I add some methods to this class and it worked fine before. Now when i add a new method it gives a error message when i call the method through client application.

```
@Stateless(mappedName="ejb/funwayFacadeRemote")
public class funwayFacade implements funwayFacadeRemote {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

       public int getName(){
           return 1;
     }

}
```

This is my client application

```
public class Main {
    @EJB(mappedName= "ejb/funwayFacadeRemote")
    private static funwayFacadeRemote funwayFacade;
public static void main(String[] args) throws funwayException {

  System.out.println(funwayFacade.getName());

}
```

Still all the method which i implemented before are still working when i implement a new method it gives java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException `getName()` method is a newly implemented method 
which is not working.

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.launch(AppClientContainer.java:446)
>       at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.main(AppClientFacade.java:166)
>   Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.RemoteException: CORBA BAD_OPERATION 1330446368 No; nested exception is: 
>       org.omg.CORBA.BAD_OPERATION: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
>   org.omg.CORBA.BAD_OPERATION: FINE: 01210032: Could not find method named getNum in class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy282 in reflective Tie  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 32  completed: No
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy148.methodNotFoundInTie(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:166)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1549)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1425)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(MessageMediatorImpl.java:930)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:213)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:694)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:496)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.doWork(MessageMediatorImpl.java:2222)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
>   ----------END server-side stack trace----------  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 32  completed: No
>       at funway._funwayFacadeRemote_Wrapper.getNum(funway/_funwayFacadeRemote_Wrapper.java)
>       at funwayclient.Main.main(Main.java:32)
>       ... 6 more
>   Caused by: java.rmi.RemoteException: CORBA BAD_OPERATION 1330446368 No; nested exception is: 
>       org.omg.CORBA.BAD_OPERATION: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
>   org.omg.CORBA.BAD_OPERATION: FINE: 01210032: Could not find method named getNum in class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy282 in reflective Tie  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 32  completed: No
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy148.methodNotFoundInTie(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:166)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1549)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1425)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(MessageMediatorImpl.java:930)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:213)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:694)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:496)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.doWork(MessageMediatorImpl.java:2222)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
>
> ----------END server-side stack trace----------  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 32  completed: No
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:310)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:211)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:150)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:226)
>       at funway.__funwayFacadeRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.getNum(funway/__funwayFacadeRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
>       ... 8 more
>   Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.BAD_OPERATION: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
>   org.omg.CORBA.BAD_OPERATION: FINE: 01210032: Could not find method named getNum in class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy282 in reflective Tie  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 32  completed: No
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy148.methodNotFoundInTie(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:166)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1549)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1425)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(MessageMediatorImpl.java:930)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:213)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:694)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:496)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.doWork(MessageMediatorImpl.java:2222)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
>
> ----------END server-side stack trace----------  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 32  completed: No
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.MessageBase.getSystemException(MessageBase.java:813)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.ReplyMessage_1_2.getSystemException(ReplyMessage_1_2.java:131)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.getSystemExceptionReply(MessageMediatorImpl.java:594)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientRequestDispatcherImpl.processResponse(ClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:519)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientRequestDispatcherImpl.marshalingComplete(ClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:393)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ClientDelegateImpl.invoke(ClientDelegateImpl.java:272)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:198)
>       ... 11 more
>   Java Result: 1

Comment: In your exception it throws, that method getNum was not found. This method exists in your session bean? If it exists, how do you deploy  your server application?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot to declare your new method in the interface.

To fix it add the following to your `funwayFacadeRemote`:

```
public int getName();
```

**Note**: Java class and interfaces names should start with an uppercase letter.